# Update panel causing css issue

Tags: javascript, css, sharepoint, updatepanel

First of all i am sorry i asked this question here because issue is in my sharepoint application but i belive its nothing to do with sharepoint, hence asking here as there is wide audience. I am using update panel and inside update panel there is div to which i assign dynamic html. In html there is like button which when clicked changes color. So consider that there are many items loaded and each item has like button. What happens is that when i click like button then it removes css from other like button. I am using user control in my webpart. Here is html code

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>

                <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdnFld" Value="Its working"/>
                <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdnFldLikeSpan" Value="Span like"/>
                <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSubmit" OnClick="btnSubmit_OnClick" style="display:none"/>

            <section id="ideas" class="container">
                <div id="divShowImages" class="row" style=""  runat="server" >

                </div>


                 <div class="row" >
                    <div >
                        <a  id="btnloadData"  runat="server" OnServerClick="btnloadData_Click">Load more data</a>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>

                </div>
            </section>
   </ContentTemplate>

            </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Here is my style

```
<style>
.ChangeColor {
     background:red !important
 } 
.ChangeColor *{color:white !important} 
.ChangeColor .heart:before,.ChangeColor .heart:after{background:white !important}
.quote .like-idea, .quote .like-idea:hover {
    background: red;
}
.quote .ChangeColor {
     background:black !important
 } 
.quote .ChangeColor *{color:white !important} 
.quote .ChangeColor .heart:before,.quote .ChangeColor .heart:after{background:white !important}
```

This is my javascript code

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function incrementNumber(id, name) {

    document.getElementById("<%= hdnFld.ClientID %>").value = id;
    document.getElementById("<%= hdnFldLikeSpan.ClientID %>").value = name;
    eval(<%=serversideEvent %>);
                    }

function incrementCounter(likes, spanName) {
     $('#' + spanName).parent().addClass('ChangeColor');
      document.getElementById(spanName).innerText = likes;

                    }
```

When Html is rendered it loads images. Below all images there is button. When you click button it increases counter and changes color. That button is nothing but a button called `btnSubmit`. 
Now I click button below one image then it changes color. Now i click on button below other image and it changes color but now it removes color of other button. How can i solve this. Please ask if any doubts.

Comment: I am trying to understand what you are asking but I am having a hard time. Do you want all the buttons to load one color, then when clicked that individual bottom should change colors?

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith see this site https://www.santanderconsumer.dk/idebank/  If you click like button then it changes color. But this site is doing postbacks when loading more images on button click. Hence i am using update panel. But when i click on like button then it changes color and when i click on like button below other image then it removes color from other button. Offcourse this is all on mylocal env which is not yet implemented yet. Hope you get idea

Comment: Thats weird, it seems to be working correctly for me, I think.\

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith where is it working?

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith the link i gave u is production link. The scenario which is not working is on my local machine

Comment: i am looking at it in chrome

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92531/discussion-between-developmentismypassion-and-adam-buchanan-smith).

Answer (score 0):

all of your fields are in the same update panel, so i think its reload all property values when you do a postback. Try to store this properties outside or try to do the action with javascript/ajax.

[OFF] I cant help you on chat becaus i dont have reputation enought: ou must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk here

Answer (score 0):

While using update panel make sure whatever update you want that must be inside update panel. If its in the same update panel then it will work but if it's outside the update panel then it would not be reflected. To make this thing work u have to use another update panel and update that also from code behind(if it's the case)...

also another point to be taken care that after update panel trigger css like hover etc... would not work. for this work around u have to re-assign all css/JS actions.

Comment: how to reassign all css/js actions?